# vlc player freezes GUI (python thread?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, libvlc, pyside2

I have this piece of code that works with no issues :

```
Media_list = instance.media_list_new(song_list)
list_player = instance.media_list_player_new()
list_player.set_media_list(Media_list)
list_player.play()
```

how ever i would like to itterate through a list, and use normal vlc player to play it.

```
playing = set([1,2,3,4])
for i in song_list:
player.set_mrl(i)
player.play()
play=True
while play == True:
    time.sleep(1)
    play_state = player.get_state()
    if play_state in playing:
        continue
    else:
        play = False
```

This does almost the same thing, and it suits my needs better, however it freezes my GUi,(qml/pyside2). So now i am cofused, am i supposed to make a new thread for this, or is there some other way to do this in vlc.

Well i did try creating new thread and running the function above in it, however same issue, the moment player goes in to for loop and start play method, the gui freezes.(the vlc works normaly, and plays the playlist, but gui is unresponsive for duration)

so just to expand a bit , this is the part that i have, and it works ok, but i cant get data from my songs during their play time, since all i have is url, and not the metadata .

```
song_list=[]
r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD6s0l-FZhjkc-TYwXO5GbwyxFqTd5Y9J')
page = r.text
soup=bs(page,'html.parser')
res=soup.find_all('a',{'class':'pl-video-title-link'})
for l in res:
    #print (l.get("href"))
    #print("https://www.youtube.com"+l.get("href"))
    yt ='https://www.youtube.com'
    temp =l.get("href")
    url =yt+temp
    video = pafy.new(url)
    bestaudio = video.getbestaudio()
    song = bestaudio.url
    #print(video.getbestaudio().url)
    song_list.append(song)

Media_list = instance.media_list_new(song_list)
list_player = instance.media_list_player_new()
list_player.set_media_list(Media_list)
list_player.play()
```

what i would want is:

```
@Slot()
def print_yt_playlist(self):
song_list=[]
r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD6s0l-FZhjkc-TYwXO5GbwyxFqTd5Y9J')
page = r.text
soup=bs(page,'html.parser')
res=soup.find_all('a',{'class':'pl-video-title-link'})
for l in res:
    #print (l.get("href"))
    #print("https://www.youtube.com"+l.get("href"))
    yt ='https://www.youtube.com'
    temp =l.get("href")
    url =yt+temp
    video = pafy.new(url)
    bestaudio = video.getbestaudio()
    song = bestaudio.url
    #print(video.getbestaudio().url)
    song_list.append(video)
 playing = set([1,2,3,4])
 for i in song_list:
     media = instance.media_new(i.getbestaudio().url)
     print(i.Artist) #THIS is what i want, i want to be able to acces that data for the song that is playing
     print(i.Duration) #and this and so on, that is why i want to loop through list, since i dont think i can do it with media_list
     player.set_media(media)
     player.play()
     play=True
 while play == True:
    time.sleep(1)
    play_state = player.get_state()
    if play_state in playing:
        continue
    else:
        play = False
```

Or more simple, is there a way that i paste "video" in to the media_list and then from there i could access data about current song, as well playing the song ?

I dont know what could help you from qml side, the only thing i do is trigger this function on button click.

Comment: Why do you want to use the second method? What advantage do you have compared to the first?

Comment: well, i am using beautifullsoup and pafy to get links from youtube playlists, then i get best audio and store it in my media list and play it with media_list_player. What i would like to do, is store my "video" file, video = pafy.new(url). Since from this i can get both audio,audio url, thumbnails,duration and so on. Which i cant from media_list, since i can only store an actual song url in it.

Comment: Why do you say that Media_list can only save a url?

Comment: i expanded my original question, what i would like is list of my "video" files that i could both play, and in same time acces data like, artist,thumbnail, duration and so on. and i think i cant do that with media_list

Comment: Before what event you want to do it. Why do not you play and an instant later you access the data? I still do not understand you, I think you are omitting more information. What is your final goal ?, According to the code you are showing, you get a list of urls: song_list, what are you playing, and at what moment do you want to access the other data and how do you do it, also if you indicate the relationship with the GUI it would be great.

Comment: there, i updated code one more time, if you need qml i can paste it, but i only trigger function, nothing else. thank you for your patience.

Comment: I haven't used Qt (and you don't mention it specifically) but I suspect that you are bumping into the old Gui Loop issue. You pass control to vlc with no way of getting back to the Gui's main loop until it finishes. I suggest having a look at a `Timer` function. http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/qtimer-making-timers-pyqt4/

Comment: @ImRaphael 
Okay, we are improving, I understand that with a button from QML you call the print_yt_playlist method. Now what I do not understand is where you use attributes such as Artist, Duration, etc, I only see that you are printing it. On the other hand, you want to play the playlist and every time you change the changes, QML will update the information such as Artist, Duration, etc. I am right?

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi, i did found an answer for time being, all i needed was that my GUI does not get blocked when i execute this, and when the song starts i have access to meta data, i still dont know what and how i will use meta data, but gui lock does not show up anymore. Thank you very much for help. --Rolf of Saxony, you too mate, thanks! i looked at timer but i still chose thread for time being, dont know what is better in this case.

Comment: @ImRaphael 
I think that is the worst option, it was not necessary, if that metadata is going to be used in QML you could have problems since the QML can not interact directly with another thread, I think there is another better solution but I do not like to think about the short term, according to what I see you are going to use that metadata in the QML and possibly you will have problems. Are you going to use the metadata in the GUI?

Comment: @eyllanesc for sure i will use it in qml, since i am going to maybe present some of the data visually.Lets just say i have a label in my qml, on which i will show artist when the song starts. the code is "working" atm, instead of thread what would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Well i took a bit time, and i have a solution, its still in "rough" condition, but it works and it does not block the gui when i use it.
I put that logic in a new thread, and i call it from there, there needs to done a lot tweaking. 
I dont know if this is the most "elegant" approach, so if anyone else have better idea, please dont hesitate to say.

```
class Threaddy(QThread):

def __init__(self):
    QThread.__init__(self)

def __del__(self):
    self.wait()

def run(self):

    song_list=[]
    r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD6s0l-FZhjkc-TYwXO5GbwyxFqTd5Y9J')
    page = r.text
    soup=bs(page,'html.parser')
    res=soup.find_all('a',{'class':'pl-video-title-link'})
    for l in res:
        #print (l.get("href"))
        #print("https://www.youtube.com"+l.get("href"))
        yt ='https://www.youtube.com'
        temp =l.get("href")
        url =yt+temp
        video = pafy.new(url)
        bestaudio = video.getbestaudio()
        song = bestaudio.url
        #print(video.getbestaudio().url)
        song_list.append(video)

    for song in song_list:

        media=instance.media_new(song.getbestaudio().url) #THIS WORKS NOW

        media.get_mrl()
        player.set_media(media)
        player.play()
        print(song.title) #SO DOES THIS
        playing = set([1,2,3,4])
        time.sleep(1)
        duration = player.get_length() / 1000
        mm, ss = divmod(duration, 60)

        while True:
            state = player.get_state()
            if state not in playing:
                break
            continue
```

Comment: where you use attributes such as Artist, Duration, etc?

Comment: @eyllanesc What would you suggest i should do, to evade spawning new thread, but also to evade gui loop ? since i do want to have access to this Artist,Duration data in QML. Id like to show artist data, in qml label (most trivial). and you said that qml cant work with more threads. Ty